# UPDATED: mod_rewrite and POST method in PHP problem, $_POST is always empty

Tags: php, apache, forms, post

Im using mod_rewrite to display adress of pages in more readable way, instead of

http://127.0.0.1/index.php?article=contact

i got

http://127.0.0.1/contact

when im sending form, all is processed by index.php, so i direct action of form to currently displayed page but $_POST is always empty, opening block of form looks like this

```
<form method="post" action="http://127.0.0.1/contact">
```

before i launched mod_rewrite all was working great, but now mod_rewrite seems to cause problems.

Please tell me what to change in PHP, Apache configuration files, or what else to do  to make $_POST work with rewrite endabled

**Here are rewrite rules that was requested**

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\.]+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&va=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&va=$2&vb=$3 [L]
```

Thanks in advance

Amir

Comment: You should add your rewrite here too.  There are different ways to rewrite, some of which may cause issues.

Although, I'm most concerned about the fact that code is actually calling index.php... and if it is just a simple templating system, I'm not sure where your form processing would happen.

Comment: What are your rewrite rules? You most likely need to add a capture group for the parameters.

Comment: Your probably have some logic error in your rewrite, show us your rewrite rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rewrite rule does a *redirect*, so the browser will instead go to this address with a GET request; the POST data will therefore always be empty.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thank you, reomoving that seems to fix the problem, can u suggest me what i should do if redirect like that (or similar) would be required? is there any way to redirect POST data as well?

Comment: The rules that you have underneath rewrite the same request (e.g. those without the HTTP 301 code).